# Translation of "how" with adjective

Tags: traduction, adjectifs

> I can't believe how tall he is!

How should I translate "how" here? Should it be with "comment", "combien", "à quel point", or are there ways to rephrase the sentence?

> Je ne peux pas croire comment il est grand!
>
> Je ne peux pas croire combien il est grand!
>
> Je ne peux pas croire à quel point il est grand!

Comment: The last two options are good, because they are somehow synonyms.
(Source: https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/combien#Adverbe)

Comment: I'd say "je ne peux pas croire qu'il soit si grand" ; I'm not sure about any of your three sentences because in each case, the positive sentence (without "pouvoir") does not make sense : "*je crois combien il est grand" ; "*je crois à quel point il est grand".

Answer (score 0):

Your three propositions does not make sense in french. We can understand what you want to say but it does not sound good. The last one is the most correct one.

A better translation would be (as proposed in the comment by @Alexandre d'Entraigues)

> Je ne peux pas croire qu'il soit si grand !

Answer (score 0):

The third sentence is ok, if you talk about something

But if you talk about someone, I would say :

> Je ne peux pas croire à quel point il a grandi!